# Firebase Authentication Error "auth/invalid-value-(email),-starting-an-object-on-a-scalar-field"

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, react-hooks, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement authentication in my site using react firebase hooks. And everything is performing well. I mean the `signInWithGoogle`, `signInWithGitHub` and `createAccountWithEmailAndPassword` are working as well. But the problem is when I'm gonna implement `singInWithEmailAndPassword` then an error arrives. That error message is,
`Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-value-(email),-starting-an-object-on-a-scalar-field).`

### What I did in my code:

- import `import {useSignInWithEmailAndPassword} from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';`
- `const [signInWithEmailAndPassword, emailUser, emailLoading, emailError,] = useSignInWithEmailAndPassword(auth);`
- 

```
const handleLogin = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (signInfo.email === '' || signInfo.password === '') { return }
        else {
            console.log(signInfo.email, signInfo.password);

            signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, signInfo.email, signInfo.password);
            e.target.reset()
            if (emailError) {
                toast.error(emailError.message)
             };
            };
          };
```

- the value of `signInfo.email` is founded successfully.

**For your kind information, I repeat I can successfully create an account with email and password but I can't log in again to that account.**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this isn't what is happening with yours but I got this error from accidentally passing in the auth object where the email should have been. My project was set up with an AuthContext.js file with

```
const login = (email, password) => {
  return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
};
```

but when I called this function from another file I was using:

```
 login(auth, email, pass)
```

but I just needed

```
login(email, pass)
```

Hopefully, this might help someone else.